# Find point on line with given nearest point

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a line and point layer. Points are not exactly intersect with line layer. With respect to existing point, how to find the new points which are exactly on the line ? consider buffer distance is provided.

[image]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question so find here again-try to create a buffer around line and run intersect analysis with this buffer and points. Another approach can be using Near tool in arcmap :)

Comment: Thanks @SIslam. Near tool generates just near table. buffer tool makes a line to polygon. so, how can I reach my goal with your idea ?

Comment: reading the docs, i found NEAR_X and NEAR_Y, as the "coordinate(s) of the location on the near feature which is closest to the input feature": http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm May this can help you?

Comment: thanks@AndreasMüller, for ur response. NEAR_X and NEAR_Y gives the coordinates of existing point feature. But I need new feature's coordinate. It may be the way that, HOW TO FIND PERPENDICULAR  POINT OF A LINE FROM A NODE.

Comment: no, they don't. they give the location on the line. That is the perpendicular point.

Comment: many many thanks @AndreasMüller. Yes, I think, I exactly want this... I test the issue and let u know the result of further test. thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the near tool to calculate the perpendicular points on a line :

1. Calculate the distance from points to lines with the [Near tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm) :

   - input features: Points
   - near features: Lines
   - check "location option" to get near_x and near_y
2. Calculate an event layer from near_x and near_y

This gives a new point layer with the same id's as the input points, all laying on the line object. You can then use a select between to filter the distance, if you like.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. this is exactly same, what I want.

Comment: A word of warning : the Near Tool is available only with an ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced (was named before Arc/Info).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **[Linear referencing tools](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/linear-referencing/an-overview-of-the-linear-referencing-toolbox.htm)** to quantify that distance in the other way round, to get all distances possible for all the points you have. You will be free to choose which distance will then suits you best.
Here are the main steps from what I recall :

- Add a unique Id to each line.
- Add a unique Id to each point
- Use the tool "[Create a route](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/linear-referencing/create-routes.htm)" for your linear entities (they will become Polyline M entities)
- Use the tool : "[Locate Features Along Routes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/linear-referencing/locate-features-along-routes.htm)" with you newly created routes and your points layer.

In the produced table, you will have a **Distance field** with the point ID and the line ID. All points located on the line will therefore have a 0 in this field, whereas far points will have some value. You just need to join with the unique ID from each point with this table to quantify the distance for each point and map which ones are on the line for example.

The tools will also allow you to recreate the point on the route via a table where the coordinates on the route will appear. Useful when you need to stick not-snapped points on a nearby line.

Please comment my answer if you need more details or if you're stuck.

- See [tutorial here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/linear-referencing-tutorial.pdf) for using those tools.

Comment: Thanks for ur excellent answer. It gives me a new idea. But I think, I couldn't understand my question. I want to create new point feature. New point feature can be created perpendicular distance from reference point over line feature.

Comment: This process should allow you to create projected points on the line :) The table the last tool produce gives a new set of coordinates you can use to create the projected points on the line.